# SQL injection and parameterized SP with limited sanitization

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When I say parameterized stored procedures, I would like to specifically exclude any stored procedure that is based off of passing in parameters, building a string, and passing the string into `sp_execute_sql`. My application will not do that.

I have three questions I'm hoping someone might be able to help  me with.

1. Will parameterized stored procedures prevent all SQL injection attacks other than latent SQL injection attacks?
2. If, on top of this, I sanitize all semi-colons from any stored procedure that writes to the database, will I be completely safe from all SQL injection attacks, including latent ones?
3. If the answer to either of the previous two questions is not yes, what other characters should I sanitize out before passing in parameter values.

Comment: **If you're thinking "sanitize", you're doing it wrong.** Sanitization is just not the way to go here. Instead, you should be thinking "quarantine". That's what sp_executesql does for you: it quarantines the data portion of your query in a separate place from the logic portion of your query.

Answer (score 3):

1. Parameterized stored procedures (or even individual queries that are not stored procedures) will completely prevent sql injection attacks... at least on that statement. What this technique lacks is a good mechanism to enforce good practice throughout an application. I'm concerned that you're looking at this from the wrong direction. You don't prevent this just by fixing something within the database. You also need to make sure the code that calls to the database is written correctly. Even a correctly written stored procedure is vulnerable if someone uses an unsafe technique to make the call to the procedure.
2. No, you can still execute multiple statements in one call to the database.
3. There is no single character or set of character you can eliminate/sanitize that will prevent this. As I said in my comment, if you're thinking "sanitize", you're doing it wrong.  Instead, you should be thinking "quarantine". That's what correct parameterization does: it quarantines the data in a separate place from the code. But this has to be checked at the client, not the server.

Comment: Good answer. The question suggests to me that user3312353 has a poor understanding of SQL injection and should learn more about it.

Comment: What can I do beyond having the application use only parameterized SPs and sanitizing data before passing it into the SPs?  Also, no one except myself, including service accounts, has any database privileges other than the specific SPs I give them access to.  This include no one other than myself having DataReader/DataWriter.

Comment: @user3312353 If the application only uses parameterized SPs, and uses them correctly, you're in good shape. There is no need to do any sanitizing at all. The trick is in enforcing this throughout your application, and the fact that you can't know at the database level what the application is doing.

Comment: What if I don't sanitize something and another developer later writes a program that retrieves data containing dangerous "latent" strings and concatenates a dynamic SQL string that if submitted in a parameterized query would have been "fine", except he doesn't parameterize?

Comment: @user3312353 That's called 2nd Order Injection. The key is your last clause: `except he doesn't parameterize`. If he's not doing that, what's the point? If you've got code out there that's not using parameters, a hacker doesn't need to cycle stuff through your database first. The key is to have developement processes in place for your code to ensure that everyone always uses parameters all the time. That can mean audits, code reviews, and a good data layer library, but should not mean sanitization.

Comment: So am I leaving myself vulnerable with my previously stated intent of only using parameterized SPs in all of my code and in addition sanitizing any characters I can reasonably justify restricting from input?  For example, you can't have certain SQL characters in your last name, etc.  (I wouldn't actually tell the user why they can't have them of course)?  Is the sanitization stacked on top of parameterization weakening the parameterization's effectiveness?

Comment: You **don't** sanitize characters from the last name. It's not that it's weakening the effectiveness... it's that it's **not** strengthening it, and yet has a non-zero cost to you to maintain and in friction for your users. If you can guarantee that **all** calls to your database are correctly parameterized, you are not vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: Preventing users from entering semi-colons and other extremely oddball characters from the last name is not hindering the data entry of any legitimate user unless his name actually is "Smith; -- Hi there".  Even though semi-colon filtering alone isn't perfect, it is better than nothing and is of course stacked on top of parameterization, not used instead of.

Comment: @user3312353, Why do you say that "semi-colon filtering ... is better than nothing"? SQL Server doesn't require a semi-colon statement terminator, so removing it doesn't change anything, if injection is what you are trying to guard against. (One exception: A semi-colon is needed before a statement that starts with a WITH clause, but a CTE query has probably never been an essential feature of an injection exploit.)

Answer (score 1):

If you never, ever, ever use EXECUTE() or sp_execute_sql (and if you are certain no function or procedure your SP uses does, either), SQL injection won't occur, regardless of what parameter values are passed to your SP.

The only way SQL keywords within a parameter string can end up being executed as SQL is if your SP causes a run-time execution of a string.

By the way, SQL Server doesn't require statements to be terminated with the ; character, so removing them will not prevent multi-statement injection if you do happen to be executing strings as SQL at run-time.